# Why can't Sublime Text find the color scheme?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have this user configuration file for Sublime text:

```
{
  "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Boron.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 14.0
}
```

Unfortunately, this generates an error:

```
Error loading colour scheme
Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Boron.tmTheme:
Error parsing plist xml: Failed to open file In file
"Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Boron.tmTheme"
```

What does this error mean? What's a good way to start debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finds theme, it cannot parse XML file.

Open `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Boron.tmTheme` file in Sublime and correct it. Most probably there is some XML syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow-up, since I get this problem a lot. If you color scheme has been working, and suddenly stops, look for a .cache version of that file, and delete it. My cached version seems to be corrupted often, and removing it fixes the problem.

Comment: I second that, and also I had to clear all my Sublime Text session data.